# How can I enter right-to-left (RTL) content?

Tags: 2013, configuration, rtf

I am about to create a RTL version of an existing Tridion 2013 site in Hebrew.

Creating the site is not an issue, the issue will be how do I take client content and get it into a component.

Without setting the whole computer up to Hebrew, how do I get the content in to a component?

I have seen other RTL sites in Tridion.

If I have to take RTL content, flip it into LTR for the component and then show it RTL on the page, it will be so confusing.

Comment: Tridion has individual user settings allowing to pick a language/locale. Have you tried picking Hebrew?

Comment: The regional settings don't switch the content fields, just date/time, etc.

Answer (score 6):

You won't need to flip anything for the content to work. 
The editing fields in Tridion support RTL languages just fine.

You'll want to mark it as RTL in the HTML/CSS of the resulting web page, and of course ensure that you use a sensible encoding across the board. You might also want to use a font that displays Hebrew characters clearly.

All told, I think it will be easier than you expect :)

Comment: I need the content fields to change to RTL or have a workaround that allows us to take a clients Word document and add it into the component's text fields.

Comment: I don't understand. If you paste in RTL content into a field, it will automatically be displayed RTL. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, it works but not totally.  We have Brand names in with Hebrew, or punctuation with Hebrew and things are not working 100%.  Mixing English and Hebrew is obviously not a good idea, but we cannot avoid it.

Comment: As I understand it, it's actually quite common to have English words mixed in -- because some words cannot and should not be translated. I don't know what your particular problems are, though, so I cannot help without further information.